# Using ldap syntax for Driver properties with JPA using Oracle

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jpa, ldap

Is it possible to use the ldap syntax similar to

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid-uat:389/uatdb,cn=OracleContext,dc=abc,dc=xyz,dc=com`

when defining driver properties for a connection using JPA in Eclipse ( I am trying with OpenJPA, but I don't suppose that matters )  ?

```
If I use 
         SID = /uatdb,cn=OracleContext,dc=abc,dc=xyz,dc=com
         host = @ldap://oid-uat
         Port = 389
```

it attaches a : after the port and that is invalid and doesn't work

The url becomes

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid-uat:389:/uatdb,cn=OracleContext,dc=abc,dc=xyz,dc=com
```

which generates an error as exected.

I want to be able to set it up using ldap, so that I don't have to keep track of actual servers for different databases that I want to use for the JPA projects.

How can I set up the driver properties in Eclipse wizard ( or any file that I should change without using the wizards ) that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Have you seen https://community.oracle.com/thread/586191?start=0&tstart=0 ? Can't help more than that, I use JPA with LDAP directly using DataNucleus JPA rather than going via Oracle

Comment: Yes, I had looked at that.  That is from code, I am trying to do it for JPA Data source driver properties.